# Determine the key signature of a MIDI file

Tags: python, binary, midi

I'm having trouble parsing the key signature of a MIDI file. the time signature should be in the form `ff 59 02 sf mi`. The official MIDI documentation says that `sf` should be a value between 7 and -7, while `mi` is either 0 or 1. I am assuming when `sf` is negative it is stored using two's complement, but how do I know when the value I am reading is in two's complement or not?

Comment: Typically, when a value is stored in two's complement, it is consistently stored in two's complement regardless of whether it's positive or negative. As you say, it would be very hard to determine the value's value otherwise. Try writing your code under the assumption that it's always two's complement and see if that works.

Comment: Can't you convert your midi to csv using https://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/ before parsing?

Comment: I am storing MIDI data in my own format due to my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely to me that, if the byte is stored in two's complement when negative, it is also stored in twos complement when positive. One of the selling points of two's complement is that the representation of positive values are identical to their unsigned binary counterpart. For example, `0001` is +1 in either representation. This means that it doesn't really make sense for a data format to alternate between two's complement and unsigned binary depending on whether the value is positive.

If you're wondering if there's an easy way of turning two's-complement-encoded bytes into signed integer values, you can use the `struct` module for that.

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = bytes([0xff, 0x59, 0x02, 0xf9, 0x01])
>>> struct.unpack("xxxbb", data)
(-7, 1)
```

The "xxxbb" value here indicates that the first three bytes should be ignored, and the next two bytes are signed numbers taking up 8 bits each.

---

It's also possible to unpack data stored in a list of strings this way, via an intermediary conversion to bytes:

```
import struct
data = ["ff", "59", "02", "f9", "01"]
data = bytes(int(x, 16) for x in data)
print(struct.unpack("xxxbb", data))
```

Comment: My program has bytes stored in strings, not as byte objects unfortunately, eg they are stored as ["ff", "59", "02", "f9", "01"]. will this still work?

Comment: Not directly, but you can convert the strings to a bytes object and unpack from there. I've added an example.

Comment: formally correct "xxxbB"

Answer (score 0):

sf is signed char, read this as struct.unpack('b', byte)

mi is unsigned byte, read this as struct.unpack('B', byte)